# Sign convention of the lens formula and its application

Tags: geometric-optics

Why is the sign convention used in the derivation of the lens formula and yet used *again* when it is applied in numerical problems? Won't the whole idea of sign convention be eliminated if it is used twice?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the sign convention, and how it appears twice? It is a bit difficult to understand what you mean here.

Comment: @GauravNayak, you can get a descriptive answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123142/image-formation-lenses/123239#123239) too.

Answer (score 1):

We derive the lens or mirror formula with the sign convention. Then in solving the problem we again use sign convention to de neutralize it.

Also we use sign convention to make the calculation simple on large scale.

To identify the nature of image.

To know where is the image or object is placed with respect to lens or mirror.

Comment: You could add an example to answer the question better